# Divisão em métodos diferentes

Tags: java

Estou aprendendo na faculdade a dividir o sistema em diferentes métodos cada um executando uma função. No entanto tive um problema com o seguinte código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sistema_Bichara{
    public static int Menu(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite o o número referente ao tamanho da pulseira\n1.Pequena (17cm) - R$180,00\n2.Média (18cm) - R$200,00\n3.Grande (20cm) - R$240,00\n4.Sair");
        int digita = in.nextInt();
        return digita;
    }
    public static double valorPulseira(int digita){
        double valor = 0;
        switch(digita){
            case 1:
            valor += 180;
            System.out.println("Total: R$180,00\nAgora escolha o(s) pingente(s):");
            break;
            case 2:
            valor += 200;
            System.out.println("Total: R$200,00\nAgora escolha o(s) pingente(s):");
            break;
            case 3:
            valor += 240;
            System.out.println("Total: R$240,00\nAgora escolha o(s) pingente(s):");
            break;
        }
        return valor;
    }
    public static int tamanhoPulseira(int digita){
        int tamanhopulseira = 0;
        switch(digita){
            case 1:
            tamanhopulseira = 17;
            break;
            case 2:
            tamanhopulseira = 18;
            break;
            case 3:
            tamanhopulseira = 20;
            break;
        }
        return tamanhopulseira;
    }
    public static int menuAcessorio(){
        System.out.println("1.Bichinhos (1,3cm) - R$225,00\n2.Bonequinhos (1,5cm) - R$185,00\n3.Berloques (0,5cm) - R$200,00\n4.Cubinhos (1cm) - R$190,00\n5.Rolinho (2cm) - Prata, Pedra e Esmaltados\n6.Ir para o pagamento");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int digita2 = in.nextInt();
        return digita2;
    }
    public static double suporte(double valor){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nDeseja adquirir um suporte de segurança pelo preço de R$95,00?\n1.Sim\n2.Não");
    int digita = in.nextInt();
    if(digita == 1){
        valor += 95;
    }
    return valor;
   }
   public static int menuPagamento(){
       System.out.println("\nA loja oferece os seguintes tipos de pagamento:");
       System.out.println("\n1. À vista com 5% de desconto");
       System.out.println("\n2. 3 vezes no cartão sem acrescimos");
       System.out.println("\n3. 5 vezes no cartão com acresimo de 10% no preço total");
       System.out.println("\n4. 10 vezes no cartão com acresimo de 20% no preço total");
       System.out.println("\nDigite o número da forma de pagamento escolhida.");
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int digita3 = in.nextInt();
       return digita3;
    }
   public static double pagamento(double valor, int digita3){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double pagar = 0;
    double valor2 = 0;
    switch(digita3){
        case 1:
        valor = valor*0.95;
        break;
        case 2:
        pagar = valor/3;
        break;
        case 3:
        valor2 = (valor*110)/100;
        pagar = valor2/5;
        break;
        case 4:
        valor2 = (valor*120)/100;
        pagar = valor2/10;
        break;
    }
    //Condição para mostrar o valor total de acordo com o pagamento escolhido
    if (digita3 == 3){
        System.out.println("\nO valor total da compra ficou de: R$" +valor2);
    } else if (digita3 == 4){
        System.out.println("\nO valor total da compra ficou de: R$" +valor2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nO valor total da compra ficou de: R$" +valor);
    }
    //Condição para mostrar o valor total e o valor das parcelas se a pessoa escolheu parcelado
    if(digita3 == 2){
    System.out.println("\nForma de pagameto: 3 parcelas de R$" +pagar);
    System.out.println("\nA loja aceita os seguintes cartões:\n1.Visa\n2.MasterCard\n3.Rede Shop\n4.American Express\n5.Hipercard\n6.Diners Club International");
    int digita = in.nextInt();
    }  else if(digita3 == 3){
    System.out.println("\nForma de pagameto: 5 parcelas de R$" +pagar);
    System.out.println("\nA loja aceita os seguintes cartões:\n1.Visa\n2.MasterCard\n3.Rede Shop\n4.American Express\n5.Hipercard\n6.Diners Club International");
    int digita = in.nextInt();
    }else if(digita3 == 4){
    System.out.println("\nForma de pagameto: 10 parcelas de R$" +pagar);
    System.out.println("\nA loja aceita os seguintes cartões:\n1.Visa\n2.MasterCard\n3.Rede Shop\n4.American Express\n5.Hipercard\n6.Diners Club International");
    int digita = in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("\nObrigado por comprar conosco!");
    return valor;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int digita=Menu();
double valor = valorPulseira(digita);
int tamanhopulseira = tamanhoPulseira(digita);
double tamanhototal = 0;
int digita2;
do {
        digita2=menuAcessorio();
        switch(digita2){
        case 1:
        valor += 225;
        tamanhototal += 1.3;
        break;
        case 2:
        valor += 185;
        tamanhototal += 1.5;
        break;
        case 3:
        valor += 200;
        tamanhototal += 0.5;
        break;
        case 4:
        valor += 190;
        tamanhototal += 1;
        break;
        case 5:
        tamanhototal += 2;
        System.out.println("Escolha o material:\n1.Prata - R$150,00\n2.Pedras - R$220,00\n3.Esmaltados - R$198,00");
        int rolinho = in.nextInt();
        switch(rolinho){
            case 1:
            valor += 150;
            break;
            case 2:
            valor += 220;
            break;
            case 3:
            valor += 198;
            break;
        }
        }
        if(tamanhototal > tamanhopulseira){
            System.out.println("\nTamanho máximo da pulseira atingido\n1.Prosseguir para o pagamento.");
            int digita3 = in.nextInt();
        }
        if(digita==6){
            System.out.println("\nDigite 1 para prosseguir para o pagamento.");
            int digita4 = in.nextInt();
        }
    } while (digita2 != 6 && tamanhototal < tamanhopulseira);
valor += suporte(valor);
System.out.println("\nO preço total da compra fica de: R$" +valor);
int digita3 = menuPagamento();
double pagamento = pagamento(valor, digita3);
```

}
}

Alguém sabe me informar porque o sistema não respeita o `while` na `main` e simplesmente quando a pessoa seleciona um acessório, já fala que atingiu o tamanho máximo?

Comment: O seu código nem sequer compila. No método `main`, as variáveis `tamanhopulseira`, `valor`, `in` e `digita` não estão declaradas.

Comment: Erro meu. Editei com o código correto desculpe.

Comment: Qual problema você teve com o código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos dar uma olhada neste pedaço:

```java
    int digita2 = menuAcessorio();
    double tamanhototal = 0;
    while (digita2 != 6 && tamanhototal < tamanhopulseira) {
        switch (digita2) {
            case 1:
                valor += 225;
                tamanhototal += 1.3;
                break;
            // Outros cases, que também aumentam o valor de  tamanhototal...
        }
        if (tamanhototal > tamanhopulseira) {
            System.out.println("\nTamanho máximo da pulseira atingido\n1.Prosseguir para o pagamento.");
            int digita3 = in.nextInt();
        }
        // Mais um if...
    }
```

O que acontece:

1. A variável `digita2` é definida antes do `while` **e não muda de valor nunca mais**.
2. Dentro do `while`, o `switch` lê o valor de `digita2` e aumenta o valor de `tamanhototal`.
3. A condição do `if` logo após o `switch` será falsa inicialmente.
4. Os passos 2 e 3 são repetidos um monte de vezes (por causa do `while`) e isso ocorrerá de forma praticamente instantânea até que o valor de `tamanhototal` ficar maior que `tamanhopulseira`. Isso acontece porque `digita2` nunca é mudado e não há mais nada que possa impedir este processo ou solicitar alguma coisa do usuário antes de ser tarde demais.
5. O `System.out.println` é executado.
6. Ele sai do `while`.

Ou seja, acho que você deveria ler o `digita2` em algum lugar dentro do `while`.

Ah, e por sinal, por favor, dê nomes melhores para as suas variáveis. Usar `digita`, `digita2` e `digita3` não é uma boa prática de programação. No mínimo seria bom você descrever no nome da variável o que significa o valor digitado.

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo. Ficaria assim então o código?
`int digita2=menuAcessorio();
    double tamanhototal = 0;
    while (digita2 != 6 && tamanhototal < tamanhopulseira) {
            digita2=menuAcessorio();`

Comment: @Guilherme, quase isso. Mas neste caso o primeiro `menuAcessorio()` vai fazer o usuário digitar algo que não servirá para nada (a menos que ele digite 6). Você tem que eliminar esta chamada do `menuAcessorio()` antes do `while` e ficar apenas com a que está dentro. Também acho que ficará mais fácil se você usar `do-while` ao invés de `while`.

Comment: O problema é que se eu não definir antes o while não vai encontrar a variavel digita 2 rsrs por isso você recomenda o do while? O problema é que mesmo com o do while esse problema irá continuar..

Comment: Você pode colocar algo como `int digita2 = 0;` antes do `while`, caso não vá usar o `do-while`. Ou então, use o `do-while` mesmo e antes dele você coloca apenas `int digita;`. E ao usar o `do-while`, você já garante que a avaliação da condição de retição esteja no final, e não no começo, e ele sempre vai executar o laço ao menos uma vez.

Comment: como assim apenas o `int digita;` no do `while`? não entendi. Não seria `int digita2 = 0;` igual no `while`?

Comment: @Guilherme É, seria `int digita2;` antes do `do-while`.

Comment: Editei o principal teria como dar uma olhada?

Comment: @Guilherme Bem, e o que está dando errado agora?

Comment: Nada só queria saber se era desta forma que você tinha descrito rsrs

Comment: @Guilherme É sim.

Comment: Perfeito resolvido então. Muito obrigado!